# Group_by a unique value and find duration, while satisfying multiple conditions in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, difftime

I have a dataset, sample:

Ultimately I would like to be able to group the data into 'chunks' where the Subject column contains a unique value and where the Folder column shows 'Outdata', and where the Message column is blank. I am trying to find the duration of each unique Subject. (Making sure that the Folder is filtered to == "Outdata" , the Message == "".

Here is the data:

```
  Folder               DATE                         Message    Subject
  Outdata              9/9/2019 5:46:00                        Hi
  Outdata              9/9/2019 5:46:01                        Hi
  Outdata              9/9/2019 5:46:02                        Hi
  Outdata              9/9/2019 5:46:03            hello       Hi
  Outdata              9/9/2019 5:46:04            hello       OK   
  Outdata              9/10/2019 6:00:01                       OK
  Outdata              9/10/2019 6:00:02                       Sure
  In                   9/11/2019 7:50:00           hello       Sure
  In                   9/11/2019 7:50:01           hello
```

I would like the code to essentially do this: (filter the Folder to Outdata, filter the Message to "", and group by the unique Subject in order to take its duration as long as the previous conditions apply)

```
  Folder               DATE                         Message    Subject  Duration
  Outdata              9/9/2019 5:46:00                        Hi    
  Outdata              9/9/2019 5:46:01                        Hi
  Outdata              9/9/2019 5:46:02                        Hi     2 sec


  Outdata              9/10/2019 6:00:01                       OK     1 sec
  Outdata              9/10/2019 6:00:02                       Sure   1 sec
```

The duration of the unique Subject is calculated only if the Message is blank and the Folder is Outdata, so the output would look like this:

```
   gr                 Duration
   Outdata1           2 sec
   Outdata2           1 sec
   Outdata3           1 sec
```

I have included the dput:

```
structure(list(Folder = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("In", "Outdata"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("9/10/2019 6:00:01 AM", 
"9/10/2019 6:00:02 AM", "9/11/2019 7:50:00 AM", "9/11/2019 7:50:01 AM", 
"9/9/2019 5:46:00 AM", "9/9/2019 5:46:01 AM", "9/9/2019 5:46:02 AM", 
"9/9/2019 5:46:03 AM", "9/9/2019 5:46:04 AM"), class = "factor"), 
Message = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"hello"), class = "factor"), Subject = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Hi", "OK", "Sure"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

This is what I have tried, which works well, I just need to account for the condition of the
empty Message values as well.

```
  library(dplyr)

 filterdf<-df[!(df$Message == ""),]

  filterdf  %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.POSIXct(DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), 
     gr = cumsum(Folder != lag(Folder, default = TRUE))) %>%
 filter(Folder == "Outdata") %>%
 arrange(gr, DATE) %>%
 group_by(gr) %>%
 summarise(Duration = difftime(last(DATE), first(DATE), units = "secs")) %>%
 mutate(gr = paste0('Out', row_number()))
```

I am not sure how to satisfy the condition where I can group by the unique Subject value and find its duration, while meeting the Message == "" and Folder == "Outdata" conditions.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Update:
I am getting output where the duration values are all the same. Here is dput of my larger sample set

```
 structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "b"), class = "factor"), 
Folder = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Outlookdata", class = "factor"), 
Message = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "hello"), class = "factor"), 
Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L), .Label = c("9/9/2019 5:46:38 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:40 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:46:42 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:43 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:44 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:46:45 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:46 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:47 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:46:49 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:50 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:51 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:46:52 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:53 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:54 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:46:55 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:56 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:58 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:46:59 PM", "9/9/2019 5:47:00 PM", "9/9/2019 5:47:01 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:48:27 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:30 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:31 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:48:32 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:33 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:34 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:48:35 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:37 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:38 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:48:39 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:40 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:41 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:48:43 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:44 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:45 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:48:46 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:47 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:48 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:48:50 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:51 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:52 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:48:53 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:54 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:55 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:48:56 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:58 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:59 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:49:00 PM", "9/9/2019 5:49:01 PM", "9/9/2019 5:49:02 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:49:03 PM", "9/9/2019 5:49:04 PM", "9/9/2019 5:49:05 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:49:06 PM", "9/9/2019 5:49:07 PM", "9/9/2019 5:49:08 PM", 
"9/9/2019 5:49:09 PM", "9/9/2019 5:49:10 PM", "9/9/2019 5:49:11 PM"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame",  row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

Comment: ok @Dave2e, I added this first: filterdf<-df[!(df$Message == ""),]  I am just not sure how to group_by unique subject, take its duration while satisfying condition of Folder == "Outdata"

Comment: I recreated the dput to reflect my first table. I am not sure what to do

Comment: ok @Akrun, will this also group the subject column by unique value as well? Just wondering, I am learning

Comment: @Akrun, Could I just filter the message and folder separately and then : 
df1<- df %>% group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(diff = difftime(as.POSIXct(DATE, format = 
  "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"),as.POSIXct(DATE, 
  format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" ), units = "secs"))   Because the filters are satisfied, and then I can just run a new script to group by the subject? ill try

Comment: @Akrun, maybe I need to break the code in separate parts and approach it this way. I will try. Thank you so much for input

Comment: If you can mention which are the rows that you are comparing for the 3 row output from your input example, it would be useful

Comment: @Akrun, all the rows that have Folder == Outdata, Message == "" and have a unique Subject value. I will include this within the summary now.

Comment: This gives me `df %>%  filter(Folder == 'Outdata') %>% mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>% group_by(grp = rleid(Message)) %>% filter(all(Message == '')) %>% summarise(Duration = diff(range(Date)))` expected, but if I iinclude 'Subject', then there will be 3 groups as 'Hi', "OK", "Sure"

Comment: Hi @Akrun this actually sounds accurate. Is the Subject column included in the code? I would like to try to run this please

Comment: I didn't include it, because it will break the code because off the 3 values as I mentioned

Comment: Your new dput is not complete.  Can you please check at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are including the 'Subject' column, there would be 3 rows as there are 3 unique values after we subset the 'Outdata' from 'Folder'

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(stringr)
 library(lubridate)
 library(data.table)
 df %>%  
     filter(Folder == 'Outdata') %>%  #filter only Outdata rows
     mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>%  # convert to Datetime class
     group_by(grp = rleid(Message)) %>% # create a group based on similarity of adjacent elements
     filter(all(Message == '')) %>% # rremove the groups where all values in Message are blank
     transmute(Subject, Duration = diff(range(Date))) %>% # get the difference of range of dates
     ungroup %>% 
     distinct %>% # get the distinct rows
     mutate(grp = str_c("Outdata", row_number())) # update by pasting 'Outdata'
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  grp      Subject Duration
#  <chr>    <fct>   <drtn>  
#1 Outdata1 Hi      2 secs  
#2 Outdata2 OK      1 secs  
#3 Outdata3 Sure    1 secs
```

---

Without including the 'Subject', it would be 2 rows

```
df %>% 
     filter(Folder == 'Outdata') %>% 
     mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>% 
     group_by(grp = rleid(Message)) %>% 
     filter(all(Message == '')) %>% 
     summarise(Duration = diff(range(Date))) %>%
     mutate(grp = str_c("Outdata", row_number()))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  grp      Duration
#  <chr>    <drtn>  
#1 Outdata1 2 secs  
#2 Outdata2 1 secs
```

#### Update

With the new dataset

```
df1 %>% 
   filter(Folder == 'Outlookdata') %>%
   mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date))  %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(Message)) %>% 
   filter(all(Message == "")) %>% 
   transmute(Subject,  Duration = diff(range(Date))) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   distinct
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    grp Subject Duration
#  <int> <fct>   <drtn>  
#1     1 A        17 secs
#2     3 A       132 secs
#3     3 b       132 secs
```

Comment: Wow this works! This was challenging for me, I want to understand and I will read through your notes. Thank you kindly

Comment: Hi @Akrun, this worked for my sample dataset, but when I am working with my large dataset, all the Duration values are the same exact value. Do you know why this may be occurring?

Comment: @TanishaHudson Have you loaded `plyr` package as well.  In that case, you may do `dplyr::summarise(Duration = diff(range(Date)))`. Also, are the 'Date' s in the same format as in the example?

Comment: @TanishaHudson can you update your post with a new dput with more rows that shows this issue.

Comment: I will do this now

Comment: Ii have updated this. I am getting all the same value for duration

Comment: @TanishaHudson. Can you please update the full dput `row.names = c(NA,` it is broken

Comment: @TanishaHudson. I get 3 rows  `df1 %>% filter(Folder == 'Outlookdata') %>%mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date))  %>% group_by(grp = rleid(Message)) %>% filter(all(Message == "")) %>% transmute(Subject,  Duration = diff(range(Date))) %>% ungroup %>% distinct#
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    grp Subject Duration
  <int> <fct>   <drtn>  
1     1 A        17 secs
2     3 A       132 secs
3     3 b       132 secs`

Comment: @TanishaHudson can you please check my output i updated

Comment: ok I got the same thing, I was wondering why the subject isn't distinct though, as there are two A values under subject

Comment: Maybe because the Message value of 'hello' breaks this?

Comment: @TanishaHudson ok, that is only because we created a grouping on 'Message' column `group_by(grp = rleid(Message))` where there are two 'hello' values in between the blanks

Comment: @TanishaHudson. You can check `rleid(df1$Message)`

Comment: I am still getting an output where the Duration values are the same. I do not know if it is just my dataset? I keep getting:   grp      Subject Duration 
  <chr>    <fct>   <drtn>   
1 Outdata1 A       2.55 mins
2 Outdata2 b       2.55 mins

Comment: @TanishaHudson. Can you check the range of dates, i.e. `df1 %>% 
   filter(Folder == 'Outlookdata') %>%
   mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date))  %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(Message)) %>% 
   filter(all(Message == "")) %>%  summarise(MinDate = min(Date), MaxDate = max(Date))` if these values are same for some of the groups, it would be the same or if the difference is the same

Comment: Oh I See. I will check!

Comment: I am getting: Error in rleidv(list(...), prefix = prefix) : object 'Message' not found   Yet, my column is Message

Comment: It is the last dataset you showed.  Not getting error for me `df1 %>% filter(Folder == 'Outlookdata') %>% mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>% group_by(grp = rleid(Message)) %>% filter(all(Message == "")) %>% summarise(MinDate = min(Date), MaxDate = max(Date))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
    grp MinDate             MaxDate            
  <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1     1 2019-09-09 17:46:38 2019-09-09 17:46:55
2     3 2019-09-09 17:46:59 2019-09-09 17:49:11`

Comment: ok yes, Its probably something within my own dataset. Ok I will look into this